# C# access image by name

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have multiple images in a C# project and I have to access them randomly. 
Let's say I have 5 images ( _1, _2, ...) and I generate a random dumber between 1 and 5.
How do I access the file correspunding to that number?

```
pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources._1
```

Comment: Put references to the 5 images into an array and use an RNG to pick out individual images

Comment: An array is feasible. An alternative not relying on an array would be in using `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject` (together with String.Format to generate the numeric resource name).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, your image resources are named **_1, _2, _3,** ...
Then you could do something like this:

```
int maxNumberOfImages = ..... the number of images you have
Random rnd = new Random();

pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(
    String.Format( "_{0}", rnd.Next(maxNumberOfImages) + 1 )
) as Bitmap;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
this.pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(System.IO.Path.Combine("youFolder",String.Format("_{0}.yourExtension",rnd.Next(0,6)));
```

For creating random number I have use the `Next(min,max)` Random's method. Then I simply add a new Image to the pictureBox.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can find a reference of Path.Combine

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the reference of Random.Next(min,max);

Comment: this is not an answer as he want to access a propertie

Answer (score 1):

See this [sample](http://www.dotnetperls.com/picturebox):

```
    Random random= new Random();
    string path=random+".jpeg";
    Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
    pictureBox.Image = image;
    pictureBox.Height = image.Height;
    pictureBox.Width = image.Width;
```

You can also use:

```
    Random random= new Random();
    string path=random+".jpeg";
    pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(path);
```

Comment: this is not an answer as he want to access  a propertie

Answer (score 1):

Just use something like  this

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int im = rnd.Next(0, 5);
Image[] images  = new Image[]{Properties.Resources._1,Properties.Resources._2,Properties.Resources._3,Properties.Resources._4,Properties.Resources._5}
pictureBox.Image = images[im];
```

Comment: Your random number would be in the range [1...4]. Using this as an array index would result in the _1 image never being used...

Comment: Nope, unfortunately still incorrect :(  Please read the MSDN doc about Random.Next(). One correct version would be `rnd.Next(5)`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx  Random.Next Method (Int32, Int32)

Comment: Don't link, read! ;) Currently, you only cover array indexes in the range of [0...3], missing the image _5.

Comment: FYI index begin  from  0  to 4  don't  try  to  discredit my answer it's a bad practice

Comment: From the MSDN documentation you linked: "the range of return values includes minValue **but not maxValue**".

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
//generate your random number
Random rnd = new Random();
string rndNumber = rnd.Next(0,6).ToString();
var myImg = ResourceManager.GetObject(rndNumber) as Bitmap;
```

If your image file name like  `_1,_2` etc. then:

```
string rndNumber = "_" + rnd.Next(0,5).ToString();
```

Comment: The random number would be [0...4]. So you would need to do `(rnd.Next(0,5)+1).ToString()` to get a number in the interval [1...5]

Comment: No, you can't unless you have an image resource named "_0". ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this,
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            getImage();
        }
    }

```
private void getImage()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.Next(1, 6);
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/image/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";
    Label1.Text = "image no :" + i.ToString();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getImage();
}
```